# How to get tweets for specific location(India)?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, latitude-longitude, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

I'm trying to capture tweets using twitter4j's streaming methods from the area of India. I'm using below lat & long, but I am getting below exception.

***Latitude/longitude are not valid: 8.07, 68.12, 37.10, 97.42***

This is my code sample.

```
double[][] locations = { { 8.066667,68.116667  },
            { 37.100000, 97.416667 } };
FilterQuery query = new FilterQuery().locations(locations);
  twitterStream.filter(query);
```

Please suggest me valid latitude, longitude pair.

Comment: Checkout this documentation [example](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/geo/search), you don't need `Lat` or `Long`, you can run the query just by string `India`

`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/search.json?query=India`

Comment: Not able to access above url, Getting Bad authentication data error

Comment: Please read the docs, you would need a `Bearer <AuthKEY>` to access that API.

Comment: ok.  I used URL suggested by you. Its working. Thanks. But I'm getting lot fields in data, also I'm confused which coordinate should I take?

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I got correct latitude & longitude pair.

Twitter docs say that,

> A comma-separated list of longitude,latitude pairs specifying a set of
>   bounding boxes to filter Tweets by. Only geolocated Tweets falling
>   within the requested bounding boxes will be included—unlike the Search
>   API, the user’s location field is not used to filter tweets. Each
>   bounding box should be specified as a pair of longitude and latitude
>   pairs, with the southwest corner of the bounding box coming first.

So, This is valid coordinates for India

```
double[][] locations = { {68.116667 ,8.066667, },
            { 97.416667,37.100000,  } };
```